# How add child node under a parent node in xml with php code

Tags: php, xml, drupal

This is in my xml file:

`<?xml version="1.0" ?> 
- <AXISWeb xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="AXISWeb.xsd">`
`<Membership>
      <ExpiryDate /> 
      <MemStatus /> 
      <MemStatusDesc />`
      `<RenewType /> 
<!-- I want new node here with php code -->
 </Membership>`

`<Address>
    <address1/>
    ...
</Address>`
`</AXISWeb>`
This type of solutions given in other language but not in php please, can any one help for this
Thanks.

Comment: I din't get the actual answer what I want..

Answer (score -1):

Here is the solution for your problem:

```
<?php
     $xmldoc = new DOMDocument();
     //xmldata.xml contains your xml data.
     $xmldoc->load('xmldata.xml');
     //if you want to add child under AXISWeb node
     $root = $xmldoc->firstChild;
     //otherwise use this line
    //index = index of parent node such as for "Membership" it is 0. So just  replace index with 0.
    $root=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("AXISWeb")[index];
    $newElement = $xmldoc->createElement('newchild');
    $root->appendChild($newElement);
    $xmldoc->save('xmldata.xml');
    ?>
```

Comment: It looks like your code got copy/pasted wrong. $newElement is used BEFORE it is defined, and you use appendChild() twice.